# SQL - Select All Rows That Are 24 Hours Before Timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select

I want to make a system that sends a reminder email for an appointment 24 hours before the actual appointment.

I have this:

```
SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE reminder_email_sent = 0 AND deleted = 0 AND datetime > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

`datetime` is the *YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM* timestamp in the database.

Using this query, rows that are much later (like `2021-10-07 12:00`) are also showing up. How can I make it so it only shows me rows that are 24 hours before `datetime`?

Comment: `and datetime < now()`? Incidentally *datetime* is a poor name for a column - you should not be using data types as column names, as it has no *meaning*.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to send emails 24 hours before the appointment, it's not `>` but `=` that you should use because you are looking for recordings whose date is equal to that of the next day. So try something like :

```
SELECT * FROM appointments 
WHERE reminder_email_sent = 0 
AND deleted = 0 
AND DATE(datetime) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```